# Using "Add Files to Project" seems to be a shallow copy

Tags: xcode

Working through the Programming in Objective-C 4th edition book to learn Objective-C.

While creating the Fraction_Calculator project with Xcode 4.5.2 I copied Fraction.h and Fraction.m files from a previous project called Fraction using "Add Files to Project". I then amended Fraction.h in Fraction_Calculator and was astonished to find that this file was also amended within the Fraction project, implying that "Add Files to Project" uses shallow copy.

Is there a way of deep copying files between projects or is module reusability just not the done thing on this platform?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" checked on.

If you want to copy the entire project as a clone, then create a snapshot and then export the snapshot to a new directory. Otherwise you'll have the same problems with shallow copies.